# Use locale characters in regular expressions with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, locale

I guess it's easier to explain with an example:

```
'gracias senor'.match(/\w+/g)
["gracias", "senor"]
```

But if I use any non english character:

```
'gracias señor'.match(/\w+/g)
["gracias", "se", "or"]
```

Is there some way to take into account characters like ñ, á é, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography), Spanish alphabet consists of:

- English alphabet: `A-Z`, `a-z`
- N with diacritic tilde: `ñ` and `Ñ`
- Accented characters: `á`, `é`, `í`, `ó`, `ú`, `ü` (and their corresponding uppercase character)

Since there are 2 ways to specify characters with diacritical marks:

- Single glyph: `á`
- With combining mark: `á` (`"a\u0341"`)

You will need to at least take care of such cases. Thankfully, Spanish only has at most 1 diacritical mark on the characters.

In Unicode, there are also characters that decomposes to English alphabet `A-Z` or `a-z`. Since JavaScript's RegExp has poor support for Unicode and they are rarely used anyway, I ignore those cases.

Therefore, to correctly match a Spanish alphabet (single glyph and combining mark):

```
[aeiouAEIOU]\u0341|[uU]\u0308|[nN]\u0303|[a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]
```

(Note that `i` flag is not effective on non-US-ASCII characters).

---

Back to the problem of matching a word. This depends on your definition of a "word character".

Let's say a "word" (Spanish) consists of Spanish alphabet, and digits `0-9`:

```
(?:[aeiouAEIOU]\u0341|[uU]\u0308|[nN]\u0303|[a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ0-9])+
```

Test code:

```
'gracias señor señor'.match(/(?:[aeiouAEIOU]\u0341|[uU]\u0308|[nN]\u0303|[a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ0-9])+/g).forEach(function(v){console.log(v + " " + v.length)});
```

Output (matched word and length):

```
gracias 7
señor 5
señor 6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Unicode ranges.

`'gracias señor'.match(/[\u0080-\u00FF\w]+/g)`

[Here's a great reference](http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block) of the Unicode ranges and their escaped values.

*EDIT*

So I came back to reference this and curiosity got the best of me.
How can I use a range of characters and be sure that only letters are used?

Below is a code snippet that uses unicode ranges to return the letters *only*. Using the range `0x0000` - `0x00FF` returns the following characters:
`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ`

Not sure of its accuracy but it was a fun learning experiment.

```js
function probablyIsLetter(char) {

  var result;

  //97-122 == [a-z]
  for (var i = 97; i <= 122; i += 1) {
    result = char.toLowerCase().localeCompare(String.fromCharCode(i), {
      usage: 'search',
      sensitivity: 'base'
    });
  }

  return result !== 1;

}


function getFilteredUnicodeRange(start, end) {

  var buffer = [];

  start = start || 0x0000;
  end = end || 0x09FF;

  for (var i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(i);
    if (char.toUpperCase() !== char.toLowerCase() && probablyIsLetter(char)) {
      buffer.push(char);
    }
  }

  return buffer.join('');

}

var characters = getFilteredUnicodeRange(0x0000, 0x00FF);
var regex = new RegExp('[' + characters + ']+', 'g');

var elementOutput = document.getElementById('example-output');
elementOutput.innerText = 'gracias señor'.match(regex);

var elementRegex = document.getElementById('example-characters');
elementRegex.innerText = characters;
```

```html
<pre id="example-characters"></pre>

<pre id="example-output"></pre>
```

Comment: -1. You are including `|` in the character class, and your regex is too permissive: it also allows spacing characters within the range you specified.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Good catch with the `|`. What spacing characters are included in this range?

Comment: \u0085 is a line separator, \u00a0 is a space character. There are actually quite a number of characters that have nothing to do with Spanish. You can check via Character.getType() and compare against constant which says "General Category...", and also print it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just for these 3 characters you can do:

```
'gracias señor'.match(/[\wñáé]+/g);
["gracias", "señor"]
```

But if you want full Unicode regex features in JavaScript then consider using [XRegExp library](http://xregexp.com/).

Answer (score -1):

I think you can match those using Unicode tokens in Javascript, like this:

`[\u0041-\u017E]*`

Comment: There are also space and line separator characters within that range.